# Extract name attribute from form field

Tags: php, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [enabled] => Array
        (
            [:input[name="email"]] => Array
                (
                    [checked] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

what would be the best way to extract the name attribute using php?
I need to check the value of email like this:

```
if(!empty($array['enabled']['email'])){
// do some stuff.
}
```

The name value is set by some external component and that can be anything and what i need to to is, always check on my implementation that this dynamic attribute is set and not empty. This form field is added by other module and i am trying to check this on `hook_form_alter` and add validation handler based on the value submitted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend changing the form POST key names. `:input[name="email"]` is too tedious to operate with

Comment: `$array['enabled'][':input[name="email"]']['checked']`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do:

```php
print_r($_POST);
echo $_POST['enabled'][":input[name='email'"]['checked'];
```

Your input should be like this:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="enabled[:input[name='email'][checked]]" value="Şahin">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Gönder" >
</form>
```

Result:

```php
Array
(
    [enabled] => Array
        (
            [:input[name='email'] => Array
                (
                    [checked] => Şahin
                )
        )

    [submit] => Gönder
)
Şahin
```

Comment: forgot to mention the Drupal. Updated the question.